# Check one timespan is greater than the other

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using a custom validator to check one timespan is greater than the other.

```
From:<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFromTime">                                </asp:DropDownList>
To:<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlToTime">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateTime" ErrorMessage="Please Select a time greater than from time"></asp:CustomValidator>

Protected Sub ValidateTime(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        Dim fromTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(ddlFromTime.SelectedValue)
        Dim toTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(ddlToTime.SelectedValue)

        args.IsValid = fromTime > toTime
    End Sub
```

I want to be able to validate if I select a "From Time" which is greater than "To Time".

e.g. I select a From Time as 11 AM and To Time 9 AM, which is wrong.

How I can validate this?

Comment: `args.IsValid = fromTime > toTime` seems to be incorrect, it is valid if  `ToTime` is greater than. Apart from that, does `TimeSpan.Parse` works correctly with your (unknown) input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"11 AM" doesn't represent a timespan, but a time. You should be parsing `DateTime` objects and not `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim fromTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ddlFromTime.SelectedValue)
Dim toTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ddlToTime.SelectedValue)

args.IsValid = fromTime < toTime
```

Answer (score 1):

`args.IsValid = fromTime > toTime` seems to be incorrect, it is valid if  `ToTime` is greater than.

So isn't it simply the other way round?

```
args.IsValid = fromTime < toTime
```